# Laravel Spark: can't create user account. Brief flash with tons of errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I've just created a new installation of Laravel Spark. Everything went fine but I can't create new user accounts. When I register, I see about 7 errors for like 0.2 seconds before I'm redirected back to `/register`. I made a screenrecording of Chrome to be able to see the errors. Here's a still from that clip:

[image: errors still]

All I did after installing was migrating the database. I'm running this installation on a Vagrant Homestead instance but I'm experiencing the same issue on a Linux staging server.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, trying to debug it. Any updates?

Comment: @user187809 Yes! I solved this by updating the laravel installer. Spark is not compatible with Laravel 5.3 yet and the new installer checks if you're installing Spark and install the correct version of Laravel.